# Grab portions of txt after headings

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file where sections are indicated by heading lines indicated by being inside brackets. i.e. [coordinates] which holds a point ID and it's xy coords.

There are other sections that start with the same heading format of, [some_string], throughout the file.

I want to separate each section into lists of lists.

Example input format:

```
[Heading 1]
ID     x     y
1     x1     y1,
2     x2     y2,
.
.
.
n     xn     yn    
[Heading 2]
ID     info
1     info1
2     info2
```

Example output

```
Heading1 = [[1,x1,y1],[2,x2,y2],...,[n,xn,yn]]
Heading2 = [[1,info1],[2,info2],...,[n,infon]]
```

Comment: Please post your reference input and expected output for this input. Is it an ini file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the lines in the file. If the line is a header, add an entry to a dictionary. If the line is not a header, add it as an entry to the last header.

```
with open("data") as f:
    d = {}
    header = None
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('['):
            header = line.strip()
            d[header] = []
        else:
            d[header].append(line.split())
```

Afterwards, `d` is

```
{'[Heading 1]': [['ID', 'x', 'y'], ['1', 'x1', 'y1,'], ['2', 'x2', 'y2,'], ['n', 'xn', 'yn']], 
 '[Heading 2]': [['ID', 'info'], ['1', 'info1'], ['2', 'info2']]}
```